# C++\CLI Regex causes infinite loop

Tags: regex, c++-cli

Can somebody explain to me why this code causes an infinite loop to form. There is no looping in it other than the regex expressions and I just don't understand it.

```
    System::String^ bytesOnly;
    System::String^ size = "54kb (54,568 bytes)";
    Regex^ r;
    Regex^ regex;
    r = gcnew Regex("[\(]");
    Match^ exch2010 = r->Match(size); 
    if (exch2010->Success){
        String^ pattern = "(?<=\()(.*)(?=\sb)";
        regex = gcnew Regex(pattern);
        Match^ m = regex->Match(size); 
        if (m->Success){
            bytesOnly = m->Value;
        }
        else{
            bytesOnly = "-1";
        }
        regex = gcnew Regex("[^0-9-]");
        bytesOnly = regex->Replace(bytesOnly, "");
    }
    else{
        regex = gcnew Regex("[^0-9-]");
        bytesOnly = regex->Replace(bytesOnly, "");
    }
```

I'm using regex to first check if there is a "(" in the **size** variable and then placing the "54,568" number from the string into the **bytesOnly** variable.

Finally I remove everything except the numbers from **bytesOnly**. Seems pretty simple but when I run it I get an infinite loop.

Answer (score -1):

I was using Visual Studio to compile the code and needed to add two backslashes.

```
System::String^ bytesOnly;
System::String^ size = "54kb (54,568 bytes)";
Regex^ r;
Regex^ regex;
r = gcnew Regex("[\(]");  //Do not need both here since I'm not getting the value.
Match^ exch2010 = r->Match(size); 
if (exch2010->Success){
    String^ pattern = "(?<=\\()(.*)(?=\\sb)";
    regex = gcnew Regex(pattern);
    Match^ m = regex->Match(size); 
    if (m->Success){
        bytesOnly = m->Value;
    }
    else{
        bytesOnly = "-1";
    }
    regex = gcnew Regex("[^0-9-]");
    bytesOnly = regex->Replace(bytesOnly, "");
}
else{
    regex = gcnew Regex("[^0-9-]");
    bytesOnly = regex->Replace(bytesOnly, "");
}
```

Comment: @JochenKalmbach, Why do you say that? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question  That aside, the quality of the question and answer are poor.